# Image Bicubic Interpolation does not match OpenCV and Scikit-image implementations

Tags: python, image-processing, interpolation, bicubic

I am trying to implement bicubic convolution interpolation for images from the paper "Cubic Convolution Interpolation for Digital Image Processing" in Python. However, my implementation which looks like a proper scale still differs from reference implementations and I do not understand why. This is especially noticeable in smaller images, like this one:

[image]

Here's an image generated by the MWE with original unscaled image, my bad bicubic, opencv/skimage bicubic scales, and their differences from my scaled image.

[image]

Here's the code I have so far turned into a MWE without multiprocessing:

```
import math
import time
from functools import cache

import cv2 as cv
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import skimage


def u(s: float):
    # bicubic convolution kernel aka catmull-rom spline
    # the value of a here is -0.5 as that was used in Keys' version
    a: float = -0.5
    s = abs(s)
    if 0 <= s < 1:
        return (a + 2) * s**3 - (a + 3) * s**2 + 1
    elif 1 <= s < 2:
        return a * s**3 - 5 * a * s**2 + 8 * a * s - 4 * a
    return 0


in_file = "test_sharpen.png"
ratio = 2.0

im_data = cv.imread(str(in_file))

# because plt uses rgb
im_data = cv.cvtColor(im_data, cv.COLOR_RGB2BGR)

start = time.perf_counter()
print("Scaling image...")

H, W, C = im_data.shape

# pad by 2 px
image = cv.copyMakeBorder(im_data, 2, 2, 2, 2, cv.BORDER_REFLECT)

image = image.astype(np.float64) / 255

# create new image
new_H = math.floor(H * ratio)
new_W = math.floor(W * ratio)
big_image = np.zeros((new_H, new_W, C))
for c in range(C):
    for j in range(new_H):
        # scale new image's coordinate to be in old image
        y = j * (1 / ratio) + 2
        # we separate x and y to integer and fractional parts
        iy = int(y)
        # ix and iy are essentially the closest original pixels
        # as all the old pixels are in integer positions
        # decx and decy as the fractional parts are then the distances
        # to the original pixels on the left and above
        decy = iy - y
        for i in range(new_W):
            x = i * (1 / ratio) + 2
            ix = int(x)
            decx = ix - x

            pix = sum(
                sum(
                    image[iy + M, ix + L, c] * u(decx + L) * u(decy + M)
                    for L in range(-1, 2 + 1)
                )
                for M in range(-1, 2 + 1)
            )

            # we limit results to [0, 1] because bicubic interpolation
            # can produce pixel values outside the original range
            big_image[j, i, c] = max(min(1, pix), 0)

big_image = (big_image * 255).astype(np.uint8)

print(f"Finished scaling in {time.perf_counter() - start} seconds")


# generate proper bicubic scales with opencv and skimage
# and compare them to my scale with plt
proper_cv = cv.resize(im_data, None, None, ratio, ratio, cv.INTER_CUBIC)
proper_skimage = skimage.util.img_as_ubyte(
    skimage.transform.rescale(im_data, ratio, channel_axis=-1, order=3)
)


fig, ax = plt.subplots(nrows=4, ncols=2)
ax[0, 0].imshow(im_data)
ax[0, 0].set_title("Original")
ax[0, 1].imshow(big_image)
ax[0, 1].set_title("My scale")

ax[1, 0].set_title("Proper OpenCV")
ax[1, 0].imshow(proper_cv)
ax[1, 1].set_title("Proper Skimage")
ax[1, 1].imshow(proper_cv)

print("my scale vs proper_cv psnr:", cv.PSNR(big_image, proper_cv))

ax[2, 0].set_title("Absdiff OpenCV vs My")
diffy_cv = cv.absdiff(big_image, proper_cv)
ax[2, 0].imshow(diffy_cv)
ax[2, 1].set_title("Absdiff Skimage vs My")
diffy_skimage = cv.absdiff(big_image, proper_skimage)
ax[2, 1].imshow(diffy_skimage)

ax[3, 1].set_title("Absdiff CV vs Skimage")
ax[3, 1].imshow(cv.absdiff(proper_cv, proper_skimage))
ax[3, 0].set_title("Absdiff CV vs Skimage")
ax[3, 0].imshow(cv.absdiff(proper_cv, proper_skimage))

print("diffy_cv", diffy_cv.min(), diffy_cv.max(), diffy_cv.dtype, diffy_cv.shape)
print(
    "diffy_skimage",
    diffy_skimage.min(),
    diffy_skimage.max(),
    diffy_skimage.dtype,
    diffy_skimage.shape,
)
print(
    "proper_skimage vs proper_opencv psnr:",
    cv.PSNR(big_image, proper_cv),
    cv.absdiff(proper_cv, proper_skimage).max(),
)
plt.show()
```

It can be used with e.g. `python scaling.py` to scale test_sharpening.png to 2x.

I made the implementation so far and it seems to work okay, but still differs. I also tried changing the value of `a` , but that's not the problem.

Comment: OpenCV uses a weird (IMO) coordinate system for resizing images. It looks like skimage was designed to replicate that? Without looking at your code, I would guess this is the difference.

Comment: pixels have area and a center. opencv `resize()` maps the ***top left corner of the top left pixel*** and the ***bottom right corner of the bottom right pixel*** of the input and output. the centers of the resulting pixels are calculated accordingly. if you want to control this yourself, use warpAffine.

Comment: [mre] required. all the noise has to go (concurrent.futures and whatever else). inspect 1D cases. those you can plot.

Comment: Imagemagick also produces similar results. If I use convert -filter catrom -define filter:b=0 -define filter:c=0.75 -resize 200% test_sharpen.png test_sharpen_2x_magick.png the results only differ from OpenCV by literally one when comparing the uint8 images.

I edited the code to remove argparse and multiprocessing.

Comment: also, OpenCV loves to use fixed point (integer) number arithmetic. five fractional bits of subpixel position go into a lookup table for the interpolation coefficients.

Comment: Please explain your images!  Also would be better to post them separately so one can compare

Comment: It's just the original unscaled image, my bad bicubic, opencv/skimage bicubic scales, and their differences from my scaled image. They're from the example code

Comment: Could you provide the `test_sharpen.png`?

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz “pixels have area and a center” [citation required]. This is OpenCV’s definition, but not the only one. Most of the people I’ve worked with think of pixels as point samples. In fact, OpenCV implements some algorithms that require the point sampling paradigm to make sense.

Answer (score 1):

It seems my method of scaling the coordinates was wrong. For example with ratio 2 the new points on the y-axis were 2.0, 2.5, 3.0 and so on.

This is wrong as the coordinates are supposed to be in-between the old points and not directly on top of them. I changed the scaling to be:

```py
# scale new image's coordinate to be in old image based on its midpoint
y = ((j + 0.5) / ratio) - 0.5 + 2
x = ((i + 0.5) / ratio) - 0.5 + 2
```

and now the new point coordinates are 1.75, 2.25, 2.75 and so on. My intuition would tell me that the points should start from 2.25 instead, but in that case the image seems to be shifted slightly compared to reference.

This implementation now matches up near-perfectly with cv2's implementation when a=-0.75 along with other implementations, with the only exception being my reflected border which seems to instead be copied on other implementations.

I put the final code [on Github along with a Rust version](https://github.com/vaisest/Bicubic-intepolation-py) that is about 200 times faster to enable testing on larger images.

Comment: Your method was not wrong, just different from OpenCV. There is no right or wrong, just different definitions and different points of view. If you had compared to the interpolation result of DIPlib or any number of other libraries you would have reached a different conclusion.

Comment: True, but I did try OpenCV, ImageMagick, Scikit-Image, and the Rust Image crate. It seems this method is standard and differences between these were extremely minor. Does DIPlib do something else?

Comment: Yes, DIPlib puts the center of the top-left pixel at coordinates (0,0). So does MATLAB — when you display an image in axes the top-left corner of the top-left pixel is at coordinates (-0.5,-0.5). Actually, OpenCV does too for some other algorithms, only for interpolation does it suddenly move the coordinate system.